# JavaScript regex to get a list of variables in a string starting with the @ character

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I have a requirement to extract an array of variables in a string. The string looks like this:

`select * from properties where city = @city and state = @state and price = @price`

I need the results in an array like this:

`['city', 'state', 'price']`

I've tried so many regex, but no good results and I'm not able to track down similar issue on StackOverflow or Google. Is this even possible? How to extract these variables that start with @?

Comment: Use `@(\w)*` to capture the first group i.e `\1`.

Comment: What about .split() combined with .filter()?

Comment: Thanks for the awesome help so far everyone! Curious why the down vote though... :(

Comment: ▼ because you didn't do your homework. Not me though.

Comment: But that's just not true @noob and I know it wasn't you. Thanks for the suggestion btw.

Comment: Thanks folks! This was great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x="@city @state @price"
x.match(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g).map(function(v){return v.trim().substring(1);})
```

This works, output is:

["city", "state", "price"]

Answer (score 0):

Lots of possible ways to solve this problem.

- Use regex:

  ```
  /@(\w+)/g
  ```
- Use `.split()` and `.filter()`:

  ```
  var foo = 'The @quick brown @fox jumps over the @lazy @dog';

  foo.split(' ').filter(function(x) {
    return (x.indexOf('@') > -1);
  });
  ```

Note: I didn't remove the @ using `.map()`, as this would unnecessarily loop the array twice (once for filtering, once for map).

For the best performance, you need to loop the array yourself:

```js
var foo = 'The @quick brown @fox jumps over the @lazy @dog';
var bar = foo.split(' ');
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < bar.length; i++) {
  if (bar[i].indexOf('@') > -1) {
    result.push(bar[i].slice(1));
  }
}

document.write(result);
```

Comment: This includes the "@", his desired output excludes it.

Comment: It's very easy not to chain `.filter()` and to create his own loop for the elements in the array. It was an example to show how it can be solved.

Comment: Is it even possible to remove the "@" in the final regex output using only regex? j/w

Comment: @myoplabo Yes, @ is outside of the capture group in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Break the string into words with `split`

```
var words = string.split(' ');
```

Then `filter` that array for words using the string `starts_with` method. To get the character immediately following the `@`, you can use the `string.slice` method and pass 1 as a parameter, to get the string from the 2nd character on.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("my-button");
var result = document.getElementById("result");

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var query = prompt("Enter your query");
  var words = query.split(" ");
  
  var specificWords = words.filter(function(word) {
        return word.startsWith("@");
    }).map(function(word) {
        return word.slice(1)
    });
  
  result.innerHTML = "[" + specificWords + "]";

});
```

```html
<p>Paste the following code</p>
<p id="query">select * from properties where city = @city and state = @state and price = @price</p>

<button id="my-button">Find Words</button>

<p id="result"></p>
```

This would give back

```
['city', 'state', 'price'];
```

Comment: ▲ `split()` and `slice()` wins in this case.

Comment: Note: chaining `.filter()` and `.map()` will unnecessarily loop the array twice.

Comment: I did add an example. You guys should play with it

Comment: @SébastienVercammen I did try to add them both in the filter function but I got an error. I had to chain them to make this work

Comment: @RichardHamilton The problem is that they can't be combined. `filter()` is to filter elements, `map()` is to apply a procedure to each element and return a set of results - they're both made to do different things. For the most optimal version, he needs to make his own loop for the array after calling `split()`.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHamilton! Looking for the least JavaScript as possible. Never thought I utter those words...

Answer (score 0):

I remember using following regex pattern for extracting parameter names from SQL-queries. This should consider parameter naming rules in SQL and newlines in queries:

```
(^|\W)@([A-Za-z]+\w*)(?=$|\W)
```

Test on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/oH0gI2/1

Also, I recommend not to mix regex with splits, maps and other plain JS.
Better solve problem with one tool.

Comment: This is fantastic Artur! I think I may be using it wrong. I do something like `query.match(/(^|\W)@([A-Za-z]+\w*)(?=$|\W)/g);` But output is like: `[" @city", " @state", " @price"]`. Like how to remove leading space and `@` symbol?

Comment: That's because match is broken into 3 capturing groups. You have to access specifically the 3rd group. https://jsfiddle.net/ta27xfjb/3/